# Android viewholder onclick updates more instances

Tags: java, android, listview, view, onclick

For my android application i'm using the ViewHolder pattern.
Whenever i click on an imageview in my listview the row get updated but other rows are also getting updated.

Whenever i click the "like" button other images also receive the image that the are liked by the user. How is this possible?

Here is my viewholder code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyModel> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
List<MyModel> data = null;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        List<MyModel> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final BlockHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new BlockHolder();

        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.totalVotes = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.totalVotes);
        holder.likeIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.likeIcon);
        holder.dislikeIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.dislikeIcon);
        holder.saveIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.saveIcon);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (BlockHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    MyModel myBlock = data.get(position);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(myBlock.getImage(),
            holder.imgIcon);

    final int totalLikes = myBlock.getLikes() - myBlock.getDislikes();

    holder.totalVotes.setText(totalLikes + " likes");
    final ImageView like = holder.likeIcon;

    holder.likeIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // ALSO UPDATES OTHER VIEWS...
            holder.likeIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thumbs_up_mouse);
        }

    });

    return row;
}

private static class BlockHolder{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView totalVotes;
    ImageView dislikeIcon;
    ImageView likeIcon;
    ImageView saveIcon;
}
```

Comment: use in `onClick` `((ImageView)v).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thumbs_up_mouse);` instead `holder.likeIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thumbs_up_mouse);`

Comment: Still have the same problem unfortunately